# Wildfly is not picking up the files under the resources folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly

I'm working on a spring boot project in which I'm sending a client certificate with every request. I have placed the client certificate inside **resources/keystore/certificate.jks** folder. However, when I deploy the application in wildfly I got the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [keystore/certificate.jks] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: vfs:/content/ProjectName.war/WEB-INF/classes/keystore/certificate.jks
```

I'm reading the file in the following way

```
public RestTemplate getTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) throws Exception{
        char[] password = "changeit".toCharArray();

       final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
                .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore("classpath:keystore/certificate.jks", password,"KeyStore"), password)
        .build();
    
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
        return builder
                .requestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client))
                .build();   
        
    }
    
    private KeyStore keyStore(String file, char[] password,String type) throws Exception {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        File key = ResourceUtils.getFile(file);
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(key)) {
            keyStore.load(in, password);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyStore;
    }
```

When I run this application as spring boot app it runs successfully however when I package this app and deploys it in wildfly server It gives me FileNotFoundError

Answer (score 0):

though I don't get the intent behind sending a certificate in this way.
In the context of wildfly understand things, it's via modules. you can create custom modules and load them in WildFly. You can refer : https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Writing_a_Custom_WildFly_Module